# WHY sort function works such in both conditions?

Tags: python-3.x

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
print(l.sort(reverse = True))
```

Here output=None

```
l = [1,2,3]
l.sort(reverse = True)
print(l)
```

Here =[3,2,1]

Comment: `.sort` is in place so it always works when you call it on a list. Why wouldn't it work? [It returns `None`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/sort.html), so there's never any point to using the return value like you do in snippet 1.

Answer (score 0):

@ggorlen answered your question - `.sort()` performs an in-place sort of your list and returns `None` when it is done.  So, in your first example you are printing the `None` that `.sort()` returned. If want to print a sorted version of your list without actually sorting the list iself you could used a similar function, `sorted`.

Example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
print(sorted(l, reverse = True))
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: sir i'm newbie on stack & and also in python////// a=1 
b=2
print(a+b)

c=a+b
print(c)   (your answer seems as like this [above method] and both are giving just same output {i'm not comparing but could u plz elaborate it further}])0.

Answer (score 0):

in 1st snippet you are printing the return value of sort() i.e. None
sort() returns None instead it just sorts the list

your approach in 2nd snippet is correct because you first sorted the list and then printed it.

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference between the list sort() function and the sorted() function is that the sort() function will modify the list it is called on. The sorted() function will create a new list containing a sorted version of the list it is given. The sorted() function will not modify the list passed as a parameter. If you want to sort a list but still have the original unsorted version, then you would use the sorted() function. If maintaining the original order of the list is unimportant, then you can call the sort() function on the list.

A second important difference is that the sorted() function will return a list so you must assign the returned data to a new variable. The sort() function modifies the list in-place and has no return value.

The example below shows the difference in behavior between sort() and sorted(). After being passed to sorted(), the l list remains unchanged. Once the sort() function is called on it, the list is updated. exaple:

```
l = [3, 1, 2]
new_list = sorted(l)

print(new_list) # output --> [1, 2, 3]

print(l) # output --> [3, 1, 2]

l.sort()  # finction sort()

print(l) # output --> [1, 2, 3]
```